# Export several matrices to excel in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, export-to-excel

I want to write to an excel file n matrices, if I would like 2 to be in the same page, and other two on the same page, how to do it

I have

```
xlswrite('file.xls', matrix1, 'page1', 'A1');
xlswrite('file.xls', matrix2, 'page1', 'A50');
```

Is there a way to make dynamic the 4th parameter like

```
xlswrite('file.xls', matrix2, 'page1', 'A'%size(matrix));
```

Comment: This code seems to work for me.  What is the contents of `matrix1` and `matrix2`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
xlswrite('file.xls', matrix2, 'page1', ['A' num2str(length(matrix2))]);
```

Hope that helps.