# Pull Out MATLAB Data to One Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: excel, matlab

First there is a MATLAB code(pseudo code):

```
for i = 1:2
A(i) = [C(i);D(i)];
B(i) = [E(i);F(i)]; 
end
```

The value for A and B in each loop are as follows,

```
A(1) =     
'Rank'    'Ticker'    '201205'    'Weight'
[   1]    'B'         [ 0.04]     [       0.03]
[   2]    'E'         [ 0.01]     [       0.10]


A(2) =     
    'Rank'    'Ticker'    '201206'    'Weight'
    [   1]    'X'         [ 0.02]     [       0.07]
    [   2]    'Y'         [ 0.01]     [       0.11]


B(1) =     
'Rank'    'Sector'    '201205'    
[   1]    'S'         [ 0.02]    
[   2]    'A'         [ 0.01]   


B(2) =     
    'Rank'    'Sector'    '201206'  
    [   1]    'T'         [ 0.08]   
    [   2]    'Y'         [ 0.03]
```

Now comes to my question. How can I add a code in the loop so that all values of A and B generated from each loop can be pulled out into a single spreadsheet like the following picture shown in the link?

[image]

The trick thing is data should be pulled out in different area of spreadsheet for different i.

BTW this is a simplified version. The actual problem has 500 loops instead of 2. A and B are much more complicated as well.

Comment: Please refer to those threads,

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5244440/export-several-matrices-to-excel-in-matlab

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8676763/how-to-export-data-from-matlab-to-excel-for-a-loop

Answer (score 0):

you can dump it all to a CSV file (comma separated values).

just add to your for loop a text variable that accumulates all the data, so it will look something like this:

(contents of somecsvfile.csv)

```
201205,weight,,,rank,sector,201205,
0.04  ,0.03  ,,,   1,S     ,0.02
```

Answer (score 0):

I typically do it like this:

```
table = {};
res_wid = 2;
res_height = 3;
dist = 2;
for i=1:10
    x_pos = (i-1)*(res_wid + dist)+ (1:res_wid);
    for j=1:10
        y_pos = (j-1)*(res_height + dist)+ (1:res_height);
        data = {
            'label 1','label 2'
            rand, rand
            rand, rand
            };
        table(y_pos,x_pos) = data;
    end
end
```

Just be warned that excel has some stupid limitations when you write these files: 65,536 rows by 256 columns (see [excel specifications](https://office.microsoft.com/en-us/excel-help/excel-specifications-and-limits-HP005199291.aspx)). One can easily run in those.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply and warning about Excel limitations. However, I was wondering how this code could pull out data from MATLAB matrices into a spreadsheet?